# Nashorn performance on JDK 9 and JDK 10

Tags: java, java-9, nashorn, java-10

If you interpret the moment.js library using Nashorn on JDK 8, it runs in a couple of seconds:

```
time .../JDK8/bin/jjs moment-with-locales-2.22.2.js
real    0m2.644s
user    0m10.059s
sys     0m0.287s
```

But do the same on JDK 9 or 10, and it's terrible:

```
time .../JDK10/bin/jjs moment-with-locales-2.22.2.js
real    0m27.308s
user    0m59.690s
sys     0m1.353s
```

This is literally ten times slower. Is it just me?

I know Nashorn is going to be deprecated, but should it not work properly while it is supported?

Any suggestions? Workarounds?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nashorn can use 'optimistic types' (more below), and they are turned on by default in Java 9 and later, but they cause delays at startup.

Turning off optimistic types yields:

```
$ time jjs --optimistic-types=false moment-with-locales.js
real    0m4.282s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

The switch can be abbreviated `-ot=false`.

`jjs -h` defines optimistic types as follows:

> Use optimistic type assumptions with deoptimizing recompilation.
>   This makes the compiler try, for any program symbol whose type cannot
>   be proven at compile time, to type it as narrow and primitive as
>   possible. If the runtime encounters an error because symbol type
>   is too narrow, a wider method will be generated until steady stage
>   is reached. While this produces as optimal Java Bytecode as possible,
>   erroneous type guesses will lead to longer warmup. Optimistic typing
>   is currently enabled by default, but can be disabled for faster
>   startup performance.

Thus, optimistic typing may yield faster performance in the long term (though that is not guaranteed), but results in slower startup.

Comment: Very interesting -- thank you for the pointer. I'm still kinda shocked that there is such a difference, but a bit more testing does confirm that this is only at startup. If you are executing the same JS code again and again, you only pay the price once, but it's a hefty price!

I'm guessing that the compilation of moment.js is very expensive because it has to recompile many times. It's not that big (~50K), so that bodes ill for larger JS libraries.

Comment: To follow up -- we are now disabling the optimistic types optimization by default by doing:

`jsEngine = nashornEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(new String[] { "--optimistic-types=false" });`

This allows us to have startup times that are more consistent with JDK 8, at the price of less optimization. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @MaxTardiveau You can accept my answer if it helped and answered your question.